# Transforming a row-based JSON in a column-based JSON in PYTHON

Tags: python, json

would like to transform a row-based JSON in a column-based JSON. I receive the JSON in a row-based form and will do some visualization with it, which would be easier in a column-based form.

row-based would look something like this:

```
{
  "0": {
    "fname": "John", 
    "lname": "Miller", 
    "age": 50
  }, 
  "1": {
    "fname": "Eve", 
    "lname": "Johnson", 
    "age": 40
  }...
```

Example column-based:

```
{
  "fname": {
    "0" : "John", 
    "1" : "Eve"
  }, 
  "lname": {
    "0" : "Miller", 
    "1" : "Johnson"
  }, 
  "age": {
    "0": 50, 
    "1" : 40
  }...
```

Is there a more efficient way than just looping through all elements and rewriting the JSON completely with python?

Thanks!

Comment: You'll have to read the JSON string into a Python object, and then extract the properties you want, to write them out in the order you want. There's no magic, here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use pandas module, well fitting.

```py
import pandas as pd
data = '''
{ "0": { "fname": "John", "lname": "Miller", "age": 50 }, "1": { "fname": "Eve", "lname": "Johnson", "age": 40 }}
'''
dataNew = pd.read_json(data,orient='index').to_json()
print(dataNew)
```

{"fname":{"0":"John","1":"Eve"},"lname":{"0":"Miller","1":"Johnson"},"age":{"0":50,"1":40}}